# jQuery Validation: style "valid" fields

Tags: jquery, css, validation

I'm using jQuery Validation and I know how to style the "invalid fields". However, I also want to style the "valid fields".

Is there some way to do it using the jQuery Validation plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$ ("#form1").validate({        

    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).css({ "background-color": ErrorClass });
    },

    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).css({ "background-color": SuccessClass });            
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! It worked like a charm :) Could you explain what is "HidePopup(element)"? Thank you!

Comment: @Mark: sorry its used in one of our projects. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, a valid class is added to elements that have been validated and are considered valid. This can be set by the validClass option:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions